# Why perl hash does not take certain string variables as its key?

Tags: perl, hash, key, assign

When I try to assign a value to multiple level hash

```
        use strict;
        # multi step before following code

        $res{cccc}{1}{sense} = '+'; # no problem
        my $ttsid = 'NZAEMG01000001';
        $res{$ttsid}{1}{sense} = '+'; # no problem
        $ttsid = 'NZAEMG01000001.1';
        $res{$ttsid}{1}{sense} = '+'; # no problem
        print "before sid is $sid\n"; # print out NZ_AEMG01000001t1
```

At this step, program runs well

```
        $res{$sid}{1}{sense} = '+'; # even this gets problem too
```

However, when I add this line into program, I got error

```
 Can't use string ("57/128") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Test a bit more with following

```
        $sid = 'placement'; # result
        $res{$sid}{1}{sense} = '+';
```

This has no problem. So it looks to me, the line

```
        $sid = 'placement'; # result
```

changed $sid value from NZ_AEMG01000001t1 to placement, and this makes the line

```
        $res{$sid}{1}{sense} = '+';
```

works. This kind of translates into

```
        $res{'NZ_AEMG01000001t1'}{1}{sense} = '+'; # Not working
        $res{'placement'}{1}{sense} = '+'; # working
```

Indeed, when I change $ttsid to $sid value like this

```
        $ttsid = 'NZ_AEMG01000001t1'; # which is $sid value
        $res{$ttsid}{1}{sense} = '+'; # has problem
```

This gets problem too.

Why?

Comment: Your example doesn't even compile. `%res` is undeclared.

Comment: Yeah, that `# multi step before following code` part is where the actual problem is. You should create a [mcve] first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because at some point you did the equivalent of

```
$res{'NZ_AEMG01000001t1'} = %some_other_hash;
```

which sets `$res{'NZ_AEMG01000001t1'}` to a string, not a reference to a (nested) hash.

The error indicates you're trying to use a string as if it were a hashref. Your data structure doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: You're right. I dumped at each step and found what you said. Thanks.